# How to keep a Form always on top without stealing focus from the active Window?

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

My question: how I can keep my Form always on top (I can do it setting `TopMost = true`) without stealing the focus from the Window currently active when my Form is interacted with.

Take a look at the images to better understand my question: the Form is on top and when I focus on any other Input control outside my Form, I can send the selected Emoji to it.

1 : An Image what I want to happen in an input box in FireFox when I click an Emoji Button in my Form.

[image]

2 : An Image of my Form: as soon as I click a Button in my Form, the focus moves back to that Form.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a standard Form, set its `FormBorderStyle = none`. Make it TopMost (this setting is another topic per se, I'm no going to discuss it here).
2. Override [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams) to set the [`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) extended styles. This prevents the Form from being activated when mouse events are generated inside its surface (see the docs about these styles).
3. Add some non-selectable Button Controls to it (the **`ButtonNoSel`** Control shown below) and set their `Tag` property to the Unicode char corresponding to the Emoji image these buttons show.
4. Add the same Click handler to all the Buttons.

These Buttons, when clicked, simply use [SendKeys::Send()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send) (a.k.a. `SendInput()`) to send the selected Unicode char to the foreground Window, casting to string the `Tag` property value.

This is how it works (setting the Emoji to a Web Page shown by FireFox):

[image]

---

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class frmKeyBoard : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    frmKeyBoard(void) { InitializeComponent(); }

// [...] Initialization...

protected:
    property System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ CreateParams {
        virtual System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^ get() override {
            auto cp = Form::CreateParams;
            cp->ExStyle |= (WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
            return cp;
        }
    }

// Event handler for all the Buttons
private:
    System::Void buttonNoSelAll_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Control^ ctl = safe_cast<Control^>(sender);
        SendKeys::Send(ctl->Tag->ToString());
    }
};
```

Add this simple Custom Control to the Project.
This Control simply uses [Control.SetStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle), setting `ControlStyles::Selectable = false` to prevent the child Control to become the ActiveControl when interacted with, since it doesn't receive the focus.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;

namespace CustomControls {
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public ref class ButtonNoSel : public System::Windows::Forms::Button
    {
    public:
        ButtonNoSel(void) {
            this->InitializeComponent();
            this->SetStyle(ControlStyles::Selectable, false);
        }

    private:
        void InitializeComponent(void) {
            this->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        }

    protected:
        ~ButtonNoSel() { }
    };
}
```

Note that this Form must run on its own thread.
If you need to show this Form from another one, use [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) to show it as a Dialog Window, calling `ShowDialog()`. This will start the Message Loop.

For example, from a `Button.Click` handler of another Form (here, named **`MainForm`**).

```
private: 
    void ShowKeyboard() {
        frmKeyBoard^ fk = gcnew frmKeyBoard();
        fk->ShowDialog();
        delete fk;
    }

private: 
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Task::Run(gcnew Action(this, &MainForm::ShowKeyboard));
    }
```